# Shorten SQL Server stored procedure using Nullable Int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that executes a command like this:

```
SELECT TOP(25) 
     col_charname, col_axexp 
FROM 
     tbl_characters
WHERE 
     GETUTCDATE() < DATEADD(DAY, 30, col_lastlogin)
ORDER BY 
     col_axexp DESC
```

And I'd like to allow the stored procedure to optionally specify another restriction to the `WHERE`. An integer comparison with parameter `@par_vocation`.

```
SELECT TOP(25) 
    col_charname, col_axexp 
FROM 
    tbl_characters
WHERE 
    GETUTCDATE() < DATEADD(DAY,30, col_lastlogin) 
    AND col_vocation = @par_vocation
ORDER BY 
    col_axexp DESC
```

However, if `@par_vocation` is null (or perhaps we could use some arbitrary fixed value), I'd like to ignore the additional restriction (I want it to function like the first statement).

I know I can use a T-SQL `IF` clause to have both statements in the same procedure, but there's a lot of these statements already in the SP, and I'm afraid of this stored procedure growing large.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's many ways to do it, for example:

```
SELECT TOP(25) 
    col_charname, col_axexp 
FROM 
    tbl_characters
WHERE 
    GETUTCDATE() < DATEADD(DAY,30, col_lastlogin) 
    AND col_vocation = isnull(@par_vocation, col_vocation)
ORDER BY 
    col_axexp DESC
```

or

```
SELECT TOP(25) 
    col_charname, col_axexp 
FROM 
    tbl_characters
WHERE 
    GETUTCDATE() < DATEADD(DAY,30, col_lastlogin) 
    AND (@par_vocation is null or col_vocation = @par_vocation)
ORDER BY 
    col_axexp DESC
```

however, you should be aware that execution plan for these queries could be not that good as just for `col_vocation = @par_vocation`